# email redirecting

Tags: domain-name-system, email

i have a "myDomain.com.br" working fine, receiving emails just fine and everything...

because we are expanding we bought "mydomain.com" also... but we have noticed that some people are send email to email@mydomain.com...

what i want to do is to redirect all emails from @mydomain.com to @mydomain.com.br... how can i do it?

ps: i dont know what is powering up email server behind .com.br...

ps2: the .com is provided by godaddy

Comment: We can't help you as it stands.  Unless you are able to figure out what or who is hosting your e-mail we can't answer this question.  There are DNS requirements as well as mail server requirements.  Do more research and try again.

Comment: @BrentPabst They said 'godaddy' provides the domain where the redirection needs to happen.

Comment: @sysadmin1138 Right, but unless the mail server is able to accept mail on that domains behalf its a moot point. No clue what is hosting the e-mail.  It's still unanswerable.

Comment: tks for the help... ill find out who is the provider and try contact them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up mydomain.com MX records to point to the same server as mydomain.com.br does, and then configure that server to accept mails for the mydomain.com domain too.

You'll need access to the mail servers, and know how to configure them.